# Datalist - how to using Bootstrap with datalist?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

How can I make the following layout using datalist? I am using Bootstrap and datalist and ASP.NET. It got the layout but it only display 3 columns due to margin. Any idea how can I do this?

```
|---------| |---------| |---------| |---------|
| Image   | | Image   | | Image   | | Image   |
| 300x450 | | 300x450 | | 300x450 | | 300x450 |
|         | |         | |         | |         |
|         | |         | |         | |         |        
|---------| |---------| |---------| |---------|      
| name    | |name     | |name     | |name     |
| price   | |price    | |price    | |price    |
|---------| |---------| |---------| |---------|

|---------| |---------| |---------| |---------|
| Image   | | Image   | | Image   | | Image   |
| 300x450 | | 300x450 | | 300x450 | | 300x450 |
|         | |         | |         | |         |
|         | |         | |         | |         |        
|---------| |---------| |---------| |---------|      
| name    | |name     | |name     | |name     |
| price   | |price    | |price    | |price    |
|---------| |---------| |---------| |---------|
```

I did try to do this, below you will find my code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="repeaterGrid" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" cssClass="row">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="text-center col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 img-thumbnail" style="height:400px;padding:0px;margin-right:40px;border:1px solid black;">
        <asp:Image ID="ImageI" runat="server" src='<%# Eval("Picture_Path") %>' style="height:100%;" /> <br/>
        <asp:Label ID="NameL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />  <br/>
        <asp:Label ID="PriceL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as ASP.NET MVC if you're using web controls which are part of ASP.NET Web Forms?

Comment: The short answer is you can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make Responsive DataList asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975990/how-to-make-responsive-datalist-asp-net)